# Wrote warnings in file in Windows from during execution

Tags: java

How to start .jar application from command line and wrote errors ( exceptionsand warnings, all what is in Console in eclipse during execution ) in errors.text on Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

it think you can do this by starting your jar with the following command:

```
java -jar myJarFile.jar 2>> errors.txt
```

the `2>>` is used to redirect error messages (System.err) 
if you want to redirect normal ouput too use `1> myfile.txt`